# When is it appropriate to report interactions?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, categorical-data, interaction

I have two categorical variables, **A** and **B**. Each categorical variable has three `levels(0,1,2)`. There is a certain dependent variable P against which I make a plot and see that there is an interaction between **A** and **B**. In my next step, I make a model when I regress upon **P** with **A*B** (`model_interaction`). When I look at the summary of this model I see that certain interactions terms are significant. Here is my question, is this enough evidence to say that there are significant interactions?

Why am I asking this?

Along with the interaction model, I also made a linear model with **A** and **B** regressed on **P** (`model_linear`). When I compared `model_interaction` and `model_linear` I found no statistical difference between the two and I also found that the AIC score for `model_linear` was lower. So, after I've seen all of this do I still say that I have found significant interactions?

Just to summarize:

`model_linear: P ~ A + B`

`model_interaction: P ~ A * B`

Evidence for interaction:

1) Plots showing clear interaction.

2) Model with the interaction terms have significant p-values

Evidence against it:

1) Interaction model not significantly different from linear model

2) Linear model has lower AIC score compared to the interaction model.

**Do I say there are interactions or not?**

Comment: "Interaction model not significantly different from linear model" — According to what test? (Above, you said that you "found no statistical difference"; I assume that "statistical" is a typo for "significant".)

Comment: My bad. I used the `anova` function from the `car` package to compare the two models.

Comment: Do you mean `Anova` or `anova`? R is case-sensitive. `anova` is in `stats` whereas `Anova` is in `car`.

Comment: Whoops my bad again! I used the `anova` function from the `stats` package.

Comment: Did you include the main effects variables A and B along with A*B in the "interaction model"?  If not I think you made the wrong comparison.  Compare the main effects model to one with main effects plus interaction.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Yes, OP did; the R formula `P ~ A * B` includes the main effects.

Comment: So in summary, OP, you compared two models (`model_linear` and `model_interaction`) with three methods, namely AIC and two different significance tests, and not all the methods agreed. It's not surprising to me that AIC and any given significance-testing approach disagreed, since AIC and significance testing have entirely different theory behind them, but I'm not sure how the two significance tests that you used differ. I would suggest looking into exactly what null hypothesis is being tested in each of these two cases: are you sure it's the same?

Comment: So here is my rationale. The reason I was comparing `model_linear` and `model_interaction` was to basically check if the interaction term is causing the models to be significantly different. The `anova` function basically does a chi-squared test to check if the two models are significantly different. The fact that these two are not significantly different does not tell us which model is better than the other. To check which is better I was using the AIC scores to compare.

Comment: Please show the plots, and the respective p-values. I would tend to follow the Likelihood ratio test and consider the interaction not significant. It's not entirely clear what "Model with the interaction terms have significant p-values" means exactly.

Comment: @Roland It means that `summary(model_interaction)` showed $p > .05$ for the interaction term.

Comment: @Roland unfortunately I cannot share the plots and the data. As @Kodiologist pointed out p>0.05 for the coefficients of the interactions. I'll attempt to break the entire thing down further. The null hypothesis in R for interactions basically checks against a main model that doesn't have any interactions and also uses the t-distribution. The `anova` function when used to compare two models basically uses the Chi-Square distribution. So, which one should I heed to?

Comment: @Kodiologist Note how they say they have two factor variables with three levels each. There is more than one interaction coefficient in the summary.

Answer (score 2):

I think you made a programming mistake. When comparing two `lm`s that are the same except for the inclusion of an interaction term, `anova` should give the same $p$-value as `summary` gives for the interaction term. For example:

```
> coef(summary(lm(area ~ peri + shape * perm, data = rock)))["shape:perm",]
    Estimate   Std. Error      t value     Pr(>|t|) 
-10.71598140   4.84042362  -2.21385198   0.03219246 
> anova(lm(area ~ peri + shape + perm, data = rock), lm(area ~ peri + shape * perm, data = rock))
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: area ~ peri + shape + perm
Model 2: area ~ peri + shape * perm
  Res.Df      RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
1     44 74326644                              
2     43 66721703  1   7604941 4.9011 0.03219 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

See how the number 0.03219 appears in both outputs?

`anova`, at least for the case of two `lm`s, uses an $F$-test, not a $χ^2$ test, and it is indeed equivalent to the $t$-test used by `summary.lm`.

As for AIC, you said:

> The fact that these two [models] are not significantly different does not tell us which model is better than the other. To check which is better I was using the AIC scores to compare.

It's true that a non-significant result is uninformative, but it doesn't make sense to follow that up with AIC. The only reason to use a $p$-value for model selection is if you believe a priori that the simpler model is better and you'll stick with it unless the more complex model provides "enough" of an increase in fit. So if you're using the significance-testing approach, and you don't get a significant result, you should use the simpler model; end of story. AIC is a different approach with different standards of how to choose a model. Use the significance test or AIC, but not both. Of these, AIC is more sophisticated and is likely to be better for any real-world purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I think we are using different anova functions. The header of mine is this: `Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq) `

Also, I found why the discrepancy is there. The anova function is basically checking for all interaction coefficients as zero together and in the regression model, it checks individually.

Comment: @boY "All interaction coefficients", you say? Ah, I now see (thanks @Roland) that your IVs are categorical and hence the model `P ~ A * B` creates several interaction terms, not just one. Perhaps this is also why `anova` is using a $χ^2$ test instead of an $F$-test.

Comment: Yep. Strange that I didn't come across this in any text book.